# Changing namespaces with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, wsdl, transform

I need to transform a WSDL (using XSLT) from

```
<wsdl:definitions 
  targetNamespace="a.b.c/s/Md"
  xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"
  xmlns:impl="a.b.c/s/Md"
  xmlns:intf="a.b.c/s/Md"
  xmlns:tns2="http://lang.java"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 ...
 .
 ..
 .....
 ......       

</wsdl:definitions>
```

To

```
<wsdl:definitions 
  targetNamespace="1.2.3/s/Md"
  xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"
  xmlns:impl="1.2.3/s/Md"
  xmlns:intf="1.2.3/s/Md"
  xmlns:tns2="http://lang.java"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 ...
 .
 ..
 .....
 ......




</wsdl:definitions>
```

Can we do this with find and replace? What would be the best way??
I have tried copy-of select but it didn't work.

I have tried with the following...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
 xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
 xmlns:tns2="http://lang.java" 
 xmlns:intf="1.2.3/s/Md" 
 xmlns:impl="1.2.3/s/Md" 
 xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" 
targetNamespace="1.2.3/s/Md">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">

  <xsl:copy-of select= "document('')/*/namespace::*[name()='intf']"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select= "document('')/*/namespace::*[name()='impl']"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>

  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This has no impact on output!

Comment: How are those prefixes `impl` and `intf` used in the document? Solely for names of elements and attributes? Or also in attribute and element values? I am afraid putting `....` in there does not suffice, we need to see the contents of the XML document.

Comment: For elements, attributes and their values. My apologies for unclear question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it didn't work"? What actually happened?

Comment: Can we assume that any elements and attributes that were in the `a.b.c/s/Md` namespace in the input, should be in the `1.2.3/s/Md` namespace in the output? And a related question: is it a requirement that nodes whose names include the `impl` namespace prefix in the input also have the `impl` namespace prefix in the output? (That would be a more difficult requirement to fulfill, I think.)

Comment: elements and attributes that were in the a.b.c/s/Md namespace in the input, should be in the 1.2.3/s/Md namespace in the output

Comment: Do you use XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: both are fine with me.